# Change Decimal Precision of all 'Double type' Columns in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame`, let's say 'df'.

I do the following simple aggregation on this `DataFrame`:

```
df.groupBy().sum()
```

Upon doing so, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 39 exceeds max precision 38
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

My guess is, if I can decrease the decimal precision of all the columns of double type in df, it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using custom schema and override each column type to Double.